# table with "." in its name

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I was trying to use sqlFetch.  The fetch works perfectly when I change the name of my table to have underlines instead of periods. So if I use the command

```
sqlFetch(conn, "HelloWorld_40")
```

It works fine.  Unfortunately, my friends are all using the real name of the table

```
sqlFetch(conn, "HelloWorld.40")
```

But then it crashes and it tells me that

```
Error in sqlColumns(conn, "HelloWorld.40") : 
'HelloWorld.40': table not found on channel
```

I'm guessing the period "." is illegal name for a table. But I don't want my friends to change it because it's a lot of people who would be affected. Is there a way I can call the table, or do I have to secretly go to their database, change the name while I use it and then change it back to a period (risking that I will forget, someone will read, blah blah).

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try escaping it \.

Comment: didn't work. But good suggestion. Hadn't tried that.

Comment: It would take a double backslash - `sqlFetch(conn, "HelloWorld\\.40")`

Comment: No. Now it's a backslash 'HelloWorld\.40': table not found on channel

Comment: In any case, it's a bad idea to have a table with a dot in its name, since they actually have a function in SQL

Comment: Why is it a problem? Maybe, if it's a problem I can convince the guys over here to stop using dots in tables names.

Comment: oh. Nevermind. Because it would confuse the other aspects of the SQL language.

Yeah. This is really bad! I think we should just stop naming tables with a dot in them. Thanks

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: SQL tables. Trying to read with RODBC

Comment: @WilmerEHenaoH But what server? Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL, Postgres, SQLite?

Comment: I would check if either `sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT top 1 * from [HelloWorld.40]")` or `sqlQuery(conn, 'SELECT top 1 * from "HelloWorld.40"')` works.

Comment: Hey @Marek. That does the trick. I told my people over here to not use dots in the table names but since your answer solves the issue. You want to answer it separately and I'll accept it so that people in the future see how it's done.  Thanks.

Comment: sqlQuery(dbhandle, "SELECT * from [HelloWorld.40]")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem with `sqlFetch` which parse table name. Unfortunately it did not handle table quotes, so it's search for table `40` in schema `HelloWorld`. You need to directly call `sqlQuery` (with quoted table name, brackets for MS SQL Server):

```
sqlQuery(dbhandle, "SELECT * FROM [HelloWorld.40]")
```

Side note: you should specify which database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

put the table name in square brackets:

```
[HelloWorld.40]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best delimiter is double quotes -- that should work in most underlying databases:

```
"HelloWorld.40"
```

In MySQL, you can also use back ticks (`):

```
`HelloWorld.40`
```

In SQL Server, Access, and I think Sybase, you can also use square braces:

```
[HelloWorld.40]
```